# How to configure typescript editor to go to end of line

Tags: visual-studio-2013, editor, typescript

If you click behind the end of any line in any editor (VS included), the cursor/caret is normally positioned at the end of the line.

However, if I'm editing a TypeScript file in Visual Studio 2013 (with Typescript 1.0 and latest Web Essentials installed), the cursor is actually positioned where I click - inserting spaces if I type/press enter!

This behavior is driving me mad -but I can't find any setting to change this...

This is clearly TS specific and does not occur on any other file type.

Any idea how to switch this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you somehow have Virtual Space enabled. Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor \ TypeScript and uncheck "Enable Virtual Space" on the right.