# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate: Caret goes to wherever the mouse clicked

Tags: visual-studio-2013

my VS2013 is configured at C# layout. Whenever I click an empty space in a file, say somewhere far right to a line of code that has ended well before, the caret moves where I click and spaces are inserted between the last character of the current line and the caret, regardless the fact that the indent settings are at "Keep tabs".

This is annoying to me. Could anyone tell me how to fix this? When I click an empty space after a line, I expect the caret goes to the right of the last character of the line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure typescript editor to go to end of line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418757/how-to-configure-typescript-editor-to-go-to-end-of-line)

Comment: You're brilliant. Although the answer applies to all files types, not only typescript. Do you think I need to press "That solved my problem" button and close this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like **Virtual Space.** Turn it off using `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages` (or your chosen language) and uncheck `Enable Virtual Space`.